# Magento 2: How to get array of store_ids related to product/category?

Tags: magento2, product, stores

I loaded a product.

Now I need to find out which stores it's assigned to (a list of store IDs will do).

Also - I need the same for category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: apparently there's a method getStoreIds() that returns just that.

```
$product->getStoreIds();
$category->getStoreIds()
```